# After upload files into ever-note, All Files are showing with same name

Tags: evernote

I have created copies of a file, name as A.pdf, B.pdf, C.pdf(**same files with different names**).
after **i uploaded these files into ever-note**, **All Files  are showing with same name. (A.pdf, A,pdf, A.PDF)**

I have checked this in Evernote web application.

Answer (score 0):

To change the filename that appears in Evernote (and upon download) use the note attribute object and set the `fileName` attribute to the name of the file.  Then attach the noteAttribute object to the resource by setting the `attributes` property of the resource object to the ResourceAttribute Object.

Example in Python:

```py
import evernote.edam.type.ttypes as Types

#create the resource object
resource = Types.Resource()
resource.data = data

#get the hash to reference in ENML
hash_hex = binascii.hexlify(fileHash)

#write note contents
note.content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd"><en-note><br/>Excel File:<en-media type="application/excel" hash="' + hash_hex + '"/></en-note>'

#create Resource Attribute Object
ra = Types.ResourceAttributes()
ra.fileName = "report.xlsx" #set the filename you wish to appear in the note
ra.attachment= True

#attach the resource attribute object to the resource object
resource.attributes = ra
note.resources = [resource] # Now, add the new Resource to the note's list of resources
```